# bulk create table in many databases in same server

Tags: php, mysql, server

I would like to ask whether there is some way to add a table with same schema to multiple databases in the same server and if it is possible to add e.g. a column to a specific table again in many databases that exist in same server. Is there some query for that or is it impossible?

Comment: You could use tables from the internal `information_schema` database and create a bulk statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For table creation:

```sql
select group_concat(
  concat('create table `', db.schema_name, '`.X (a int, b int);') separator '\n'
) as qry
from information_schema.schemata db
where db.schema_name in ('test', 'test_db');
```

Created result:

```sql
create table `test`.X (a int, b int);
create table `test_db`.X (a int, b int);
```

Copy the result and execute.

Same way you can create a bulk ALTER query.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response. I have some questions: schema_name is the name of the database ('test',test_db) that i need to create the table, .X is the name of the table and a,b are the columns?

Comment: Correct. You can use another condition like `where db.schema_name like 'project_%'`. But i think a white list is the better way for this critical task.